# How can I move these ng-init into the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an ng-repeat to print out many food item inputs. I am currently using ng-init to initialise the values of the inputs, like so:

```
 <div class="formitem" ng-repeat="food in foodlist" ng-init="food.slider=0; food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];">
```

However, I want to do some more complicated processing on the initialised values. Namely, I want to check if the `food` in `foodlist` already exists in the array `editedFood`. If it does, then use the values stored in `editedFood` as the initial values. If not, use 0 as the initial values.

So, I guess that I need to move this processing out of the mark-up and over to the controller, but I don't understand Angular well enough to understand where & how to do this. This ng-repeat sits inside controller FoodCtrl:

```
myApp.controller('FoodCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $anchorScroll, $filter) { }
```

Should I do this initialise-processing inside FoodCtrl? How can I initialise the values of `food.slider` and `food.unit.selected` for each `food in foodlist` inside of FoodCtrl?

## [The Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2q9WRB4aSyHPNe8CCRrH?p=preview)

---

UPDATE

I've now tried adding variations on this into `FoodCtrl`, both into the top level of the controller and into functions, with no luck:

```
 $scope.foodlist.food.slider = 0;
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'slider' of undefined`

```
 $scope.food.slider = 0;
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'slider' of undefined`

```
if ($scope.foodlist.food.slider !== undefined) {
  console.log("slider")
  $scope.foodlist.food.slider = 0;
}
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'slider' of undefined`

```
$scope.foodlist.forEach(function(food) {
    food.slider = 0;
    food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];
  });
```

Error: `TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'``

I'm feeling pretty stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller just add something like this.

```
$scope.foodlist.forEach(function(food) {
    food.slider = 0;
    food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];
});
```

Comment: I get an error that forEach can't be run on undefined. The AngularJS forEach docs say something different, but I also can't get this to work: angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
  this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);

Comment: Just use an old fashioned for loop then. for (var i = 0; i < $scope.foodlist.length; i++) { $scope.foodlist[i].slider = 0; $scope.foodlist[i].unit.selected = $scope.foodlist[i].unit[0]; }

Answer (score 0):

The ng-init directives will add the properties off of the current scope.

So what you are doing is equivalent to this (inside the controller):

```
//ng-init="food.slider=0; food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];
$scope.food.slider = 0;
$scope.food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];
```

Note that these will be set once per the controller initialized.

You may need more complex logic to handle if things are defined or if they should have their default set.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit

**EDITTED**

Misinterpreted what you were try to do...  Here is the correct way.

```
$scope.foodlist.forEach(function(food){
    food.slider = 0;
    food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];
});
```

Comment: I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'slider' of undefined" if I put it into the top level of FoodCtrl, and also if I put it into the loadFood() function.

Comment: You need to make sure food item is declared.  So for each of the items in foodlist you need to set the property.  See editted answer.

Comment: Is foodlist in the scope of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing it by adding a function, `foodInit(food)`, to the controller:

```
$scope.foodInit = function(food) {
 food.slider = 0;
 food.unit.selected = food.unit[0];
 console.log(food)
}
```

And calling it with ng-init:

```
<div class="formitem" ng-repeat="food in foodlist" ng-init="foodInit(food)">
```

No idea if that is ideal, but it's working.